# Doctrine2: How to set all tables to collate with UTF8

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine with Symfony2. 
My config.yml file looks something like this:-

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: %database_driver%
        host: %database_host%
        port: %database_port%
        dbname: %database_name%
        user: %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset: UTF8
```

Unfortunately my tables are not collating to the UTF8_general_ci or UTF8_unicode_ci
I tried

```
collate: utf8_unicode_ci
```

But Doctrine2 didn't recognize the option.

How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `charset: UTF8` option is just useful to ask Doctrine to execute `SET NAMES UTF-8` on each page. I don't have any specific configuration for Doctrine, and my tables are by default in `utf8_general_ci` InnoDB.
Read this part of the documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-do-i-set-the-charset-and-collation-for-mysql-tables, it answers your question:

> You can’t set these values inside the annotations, yml or xml mapping
>   files. To make a database work with the default charset and collation
>   you should configure MySQL to use it as default charset, or create the
>   database with charset and collation details. This way they get
>   inherited to all newly created database tables and columns.

Comment: Thanks @Nanocom, but I am still wondering. Since its just an extra query that needs to be executed, why wouldn't doctrine not allow something like this.

Comment: I mean, for doctrine its just about running an additional: SET NAMES 'charset_name' COLLATE 'collation_name' ; Why is it not configurable?

The reason why its important for me is, because there are integrity constraints in my schema. So I often need to drop my database before recreating the schema and loading the fixtures. And its a pain to and create a new database with UTF8 charset and collation everytime.

Comment: There is no collation for the SET NAMES UTF-8 query. And you should configure your MySQL server correctly, too. In your my.cnf, you have to add the lines `character-set-server=utf8` and
`skip-character-set-client-handshake` at the end of the [mysqld] section.

Comment: And your integrity constraints should not impose to drop and create the database all the time, you are mistaken somewhere...

Comment: Thanks @Nanocom, incidentally I didn't have a my.cnf file in <xampp>mysql/bin/ I created it and inserted the charset and collation settings and it worked. Appreciate your support.

Comment: NO, this is wrong! It's possible to set collation, table name, coding and table engine so I can't understand why this wrong answer gets a lot of voices. Right answer gives Rickard2 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14769520/1225291). Set them like this options={"collate"="utf16_latin_ci", "charset"="utf16", "engine"="MyISAM"}

Comment: This link is dead now

Answer (score 28):

The behavior of collate has changed in doctrine: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2139

The collation is now set to utf8_unicode_ci if you don't specify anything at the table level. The way to go right now is to add it to options in your table declaration:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(options={"collate"="utf8_swedish_ci"})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

This will generate the correct collation for the table:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --env=test | grep swedish
...  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I've filed an issue for the documentation to be updated to reflect this behaviour.

Comment: As a note - this syntax works only on initial table creation. If you need to alter collation for existing table you will have to drop it first. Check how it [actually works](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/6fb7312d208c9d6f45015953f367e5c33b2bdd5a/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php#L475-L478)

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE:**

See Symfony3.1 book for reference ([click here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)):

Also notice the use of **utf8mb4** instead of plain utf8. ("Symfony recommends utf8mb4 against MySQL's utf8 character set, since it does not support 4-byte unicode characters, and strings containing them will be truncated. This is fixed by the newer [utf8mb4 character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).")

> Setting UTF8 defaults for MySQL is as simple as adding a few lines to
>   your configuration file (typically my.cnf):

```
[mysqld]
# Version 5.5.3 introduced "utf8mb4", which is recommended
collation-server     = utf8mb4_general_ci # Replaces utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4            # Replaces utf8
```

> You can also change the defaults for Doctrine so that the generated
>   SQL uses the correct character set.

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Nice ! Note, that said, that it will only apply to tables and fields created after this setting. For existing tables you will also need to manually alter them AND all the string fields, one by one.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you try add this setting to your Doctrine configuration:

```
    options:
        1002: "SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"
```

So it looks like this:

```
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            driver: %database_driver%
            host: %database_host%
            port: %database_port%
            dbname: %database_name%
            user: %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            charset: UTF8
            options:
                1002: "SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"
```

As a reference Doctrine Configuration:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#reference-dbal-configuration

And in case you are using MySql:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

BTW. I had problems with displaying polish characters and adding only set names without collation (as below) helped.

```
    options:
        1002: "SET NAMES 'UTF8'
```

Comment: Thanks! That help'd me for my polish characters :)

Comment: Same here ;). Thank You, Sir.

Answer (score 8):

Use code below to set collation, engine and charset (annotation example):

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(
*     name="temporary", 
*     options={"collate":"utf8_general_ci", "charset":"utf8", "engine":"MyISAM"}
* )  
* @ORM\Entity
*/
```

Source: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

Comment: This link is dead now

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html if you are using ORMs like Doctrine.

Particularly: adding/editing the `[mysqld]` block in your **my.cnf** (usually found in */etc/my.cnf* or *xampp/mysql/my.cnf*)

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 4):

I've got this problems with fetching data which includes polish characters from database. It looks like:

[effects of displaying data from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej585.jpg)

my config.yml is like:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    options:
         1002:  "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
```

and I've been searching for an answer for couple of hours - Im so tired of this. "1002: SET NAMES 'utf8'" Doesnt work for me. But when I tryed to access my db from simple php script (out of symfony) the effect was the same but when I added line:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

it worked properly. So it seems to be little strange. All the tables in my db have 'utf8_unicode_ci' set.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problems. By search the code, I find the code in 
vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php

```
if ( ! isset($options['collate'])) {
  $options['collate'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
}
```

So I changed it to 'utf8_general_ci', and it worked. All of tables' collation changed to `utf8_general_ci` after rebuild, but I still have one question: when I changed the annotations, I got the following error message:

> [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\Table declared on class Gvsun\UserBundle\Entity\User does not have a property named "collation". Available properties: name, schema, indexes, uniqueConstraints, options

I search the documentation of Doctrine, but I didn't find the 'option' property, can someone tell me how to use options property, I think it might be able to change collate in annotations settings?

Comment: Note this in "vendor\doctrine\dbal\UPGRADE" : `# Upgrade to 2.3
 ## Creating MySQL Tables now defaults to UTF-8

If you are creating a new MySQL Table through the Doctrine API, charset/collate are
now set to 'utf8'/'utf8_unicode_ci' by default. Previously the MySQL server defaults were used.`

Answer (score 0):

I create manually my data base with with UTF8 collate (ex. with phpmyadmin). If I do this, all tables create with command doctrine:schema:create will have collate utf8.

Comment: Sure thanks @smoreno, for now I have also done that. But I am looking for a configurable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had have the same problem, and after reading [this documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/faq.html#frequently-asked-questions) from doctrine project page I decided to abandon solution with yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used `options: collate` in YML configuration of Symfony 2.7.

```
MyBundle\Entity\Company:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: MyBundle\Repository\CompanyRepository
    table: company
    options:
        collate: utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a way to have migrations be created correctly you should setup the connection

you can set the default_table_options connection option to achieve this:
in symfony this is done through:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8
            collate: utf8_general_ci
```

for those looking to do it in plain doctrine this translates to doctrine connection option defaultDatabaseOptions, and is passed to the entity manager together with your database credentials etc:

```
[
    ...
    'driver' => ...
    'user' => ...
    ...
    'defaultDatabaseOptions' => [
         'charset' => 'utf8',
         'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci'
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since DoctrineBundle 2.0, `utf8mb4` is the default value for MySQL. So, you don't need to configure anything anymore.

See https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.0.md

Answer (score 0):

@ORM\Table(name="user", options={"collate"="utf8_unicode_ci", "charset"="utf8 ", "engine"="InnoDB"})