# Set utf8 charset for doctrine issue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using this config for my doctrine:

```
$config = array(
        'name'          =>  'backend',
        'host'          =>  'xxxxx',
        'user'          =>  'xxxx',
        'password'      =>  'xxxxx',        
        'dbname'        =>  'xxxx', 
        'driver'        =>  'pdo_mysql',
        'charset'       =>  'UTF8',

    );
```

But my database's using `utf8_general_ci`. In result, when i get data from database, some characters can't show correctly as i want.
I tried adding:

```
'driveroptions'=>array(1002=>"SET NAMES utf8")
```

But it doesn't work.
Could someone help me.

Comment: You can’t set these values inside the annotations, yml or xml mapping files. To make a database work with the default charset and collation you should configure MySQL to use it as default charset, or create the database with charset and collation details. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9005158/2689199

Comment: are you going to tell me just thorw all my 2 months project for this???

Comment: I don't mean it. Kindly have a look at respective link. It show you how you can achieve it by configuring mysqld or by updating entity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The character set and collation are 2 different things. I think you have 2 options.

1) Set the character set in MySQL config (the my.cnf file), by adding these lines in the [mysqld] block.

e.g.

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

2) Try setting the collation in Doctrine config via 'options' setting.

e.g.

```
charset: UTF8
options:
    1002: "SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"
```

Comment: i can't use the first method. So i used the second one but didn't work.

Comment: I edited a bit base on your :`'charset'  => 'UTF8',
  'driverOptions' => array('1002'=> "SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'"), code:` and it works well

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping.