# How to create a database with a specific chaset and collation, when using doctrine:database:create?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, symfony-console

The short version first:

I want the command `doctrine:database:create` to create the database with the correct/defined charset and collation. How to achieve that? (In the best case without to change any global settings on the server.)

---

The detailed version:

The context is a Symfony 4 application and Doctrine 2. DBMS: MySQL, OS: Ubuntu 14.04. I want to create the database with Doctrine:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

The SQL statement executed Doctrine in the background is:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb`
```

Means: It doesn't use the `charset` and `collate` settings from the `.../config/packages/doctrine.yaml` and also the `DATABASE_URL` in the `.../.env` is ignored.

**`.../config/packages/doctrine.yaml`**

```
parameters:
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Base/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Base\Entity'
                alias: App
```

**`.../.env`**

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:pwd@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?charset=utf8mb4
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

The database `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME` is then `latin1` and the `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME` is `latin1_swedish_ci`:

```
SELECT
    `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME`, `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME`
FROM
    information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE
    schema_name = 'mydb'
;

+----------------------------+------------------------+
| DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| latin1                     | latin1_swedish_ci      |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some another answers:
[Doctrine2: How to set all tables to collate with UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003864/doctrine2-how-to-set-all-tables-to-collate-with-utf8)

They recommend to use collate in the entity itself, but you need to specify all entites like this, and if you have a lot of them, it's a problem

```
@ORM\Table(options={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
```

The second approach is to use options in the `doctrine.yml`

```
 doctrine:
  dbal:
        options:
            1002: "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"
```

And the third solution is to edit the mysql config file and add the default charset there.

**my.cnf**

```
 [mysqld]
    character-set-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**MySQL GLOBAL VARIABLES** (for the current session)

```
SET GLOBAL `character_set_server` = 'utf8mb4';
SET GLOBAL `collation_server` = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To the solutions: 1. Setting the charset explicitly for every single table is something, I'd like to avoid. I want to have this on the database level. 2. The option `1002` don't work for me. `1002: "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"` causes a DB error (`An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[42000] [1115] Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'`). So I changed it to `utf8mb4`. No error, but also no effect -- the database is created with charset `latin1` & collation `latin1_swedish_ci`. 3. These settings in `my.cnf` seem to be ignored. What works is `SET GLOBAL`.

Comment: @automatix like this? 1002: "SET GLOBAL 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"? Post our answer how you did that :)

Comment: Just updated your answer. But actually it's what I wanted to avoid -- server wide changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the current doctrine version (doctrine/dbal v2.10.0) does not support creating mysql databases with other than default charset and collation. The Symfony command `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` calls `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform::getCreateDatabaseSQL()` in the background.

```
    public function getCreateDatabaseSQL($name)
    {
        return 'CREATE DATABASE ' . $name;
    }
```

See https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/c950aab16457b1b4fd4b0f78b976fbdec373473a/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php#L352

There is no charset or collation added from Symfony configuration tree :-( Why not? ^^

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'

        # Only needed for MySQL (ignored otherwise)
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

So currently it is not supported.