# How to change column charset and collation with Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a Symfony 3.4 project and I want for some columns of a table to use charset `utf8mb4`. The aim behind this is to allow emojis.

Here is an abstract of my Doctrine entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 */
class Category {
    // ...

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;
}
```

I first updated doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine:
  charset: utf8mb4
```

Then, I updated the Doctrine configuration of the field `category.description`:

```
-    * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
+    * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=191, options={"charset"="utf8mb4"})
```

Note that I changed the length from 255 to 191 as `utf8mb4` uses 4 bytes instead of 3 for `utf8`.

Finally, I ran update command:

```sh
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

What returned:

```sql
ALTER TABLE categories CHANGE description description VARCHAR(191)  NOT NULL;
```

As you can see, there is no update about charset. Moreover, we can see a double whitespace between keywords `VARCHAR(191)` and `NOT`, letting suppose there should be something here.
The query I expect would be like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE categories MODIFY `description` VARCHAR(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

I then ran the update command:

```sh
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But when I re-run the `--dump-sql` command it returns the same query (with the double whitespaces) over and over.

Even when I manually set the charset of the column to `utf8mb4` the query is still the same.

I use v2.6.3 of [doctrine/orm](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm).

Did I miss something in my configuration?
Does Doctrine handle column charset?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003864/doctrine2-how-to-set-all-tables-to-collate-with-utf) does not answer my question as it's about changing collation of **all** tables. In my case I want to change collation of a single column of a specific table.

Comment: [Doctrine won't do this for you](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7485#issuecomment-441248544).

Comment: If Doctrine doesn't do this for me what is the option `{"charset"="utf8mb4"}` for?

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-do-i-set-the-charset-and-collation-for-mysql-tables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine2: How to set all tables to collate with UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003864/doctrine2-how-to-set-all-tables-to-collate-with-utf8)

Comment: Not really. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003864/doctrine2-how-to-set-all-tables-to-collate-with-utf8) is about changing collation of **all** tables. In my case I whant to change collation of a single column of a specific table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

[Doctrine won't do this for you.](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7485#issuecomment-441248544)

## Alternative solution

Using [DoctrineMigrationBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) allows to create migrations in plain SQL. Thus, you can edit auto-generated migrations to add charset/collation on desired columns.

Generate a new blank migration:

```sh
bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate
```

Then, add the `ALTER` statement:

```php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

final class Version20200113131732 extends AbstractMigration {
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void {
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE categories MODIFY `description` VARCHAR(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void {
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE categories MODIFY `description` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL;');        
    }
}
```

Finally, just run the migration:

```sh
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like doctrine partialy supports the change of collation on columns  (only supported by Drizzle, Mysql, PostgreSQL>=9.1, Sqlite and SQLServer).

See [doctrine annotations reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#column)

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
     */
    class Category {
        // ...
    
        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, options={"collation"="ascii_general_ci"})
         */
        private $description;
    }
```